# Deterministic function

Tags: definition

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08642) paper the author speaks of "*deterministic function*". I could find no standard definition of what a deterministic function is. Do you know what he might be referring to?

Comment: Deterministic is same as non-random. A constant random variable is deterministic.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So essentially any standard function.

Comment: @Cesare Yes. Functions, in the strict mathematical sense, are always deterministic, since the output of a mathematical function is entirely determined by its input. However, the term "random function" is sometimes used informally to refer to what is more formally called a "random process" or "stochastic process".